# Possible to have multiple replication entries in pg_hba.conf? (multiple slaves)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Right now I just have 1 slave DB that is recieving streaming binary replication from the master.

In my master's pg_hba.conf file, I have this entry.

```
host  replication   all   98.10.144.135/24      trust
```

Is it possible to add another entry with another IP? Will that enable streaming replication from master to the 2 slave servers?

Comment: From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-SETUP): "*You can have any number of standby servers*"

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to add another entry with another IP? Will that enable streaming replication from master to the 2 slave servers?

Yes, and yes. Of course, you still have to set up the slave with a `pg_basebackup` and add an appropriate `recovery.conf`.

Your current entry already allows all 254 servers from 98.10.144.1 to 98.10.144.254 to receive streaming replication data from your server, by the way. The last octet of the IP address, `.135`, is *masked out* (effectively ignored) by the netmask length of `/24`. If you don't understand why, see [`CIDR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) and [`subnetwork`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).

That might potentially mean that anybody at the netblock owner can access your server for replication. `whois 98.10.144.135` says that is VoIP Residential, 1000 Picture Parkway, Webster, NY with control of `98.10.144.0/22`. That might include their customers. So unless you *are* that company and control that network, change your settings to specify the exact server IP /32 now.

It's generally an incredibly bad idea to use `trust` with anything more than a single /32 IP, and even then only on a network you control. You should really be getting your replicas to authenticate, and if it's over a remote network should be using SSL.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i'll change that in my config. My archive_command in postgresql.conf rsyncs to 1 of the slaves, do I just append another command for the 2nd slave? Something like this? archive_command = 'rsync -a %p postgres@SLAVE_IP1:/home/postgres/data/wals/%f </dev/null; rsync -a %p postgres@SLAVE_IP2:/home/postgres/data/wals/%f </dev/null'

Comment: @HenleyChiu The WAL archiving bit is trickier if you're pushing to the slaves. In multi-slave configs, you often tend to push the archives to a shared location then have each slave's `restore_command` retrieve them. Otherwise you need logic to make sure `archive_command` only succeeds if *both* commands succeed - so at least use `&&` instead of `;`. Smarter scripts record when each individual WAL is sent to avoid repeating the work for the first server when the second fails.